# Communities list icon is nearly identical to Firefox icon

Tags: feature-request, design, top-bar

I erroneously placed this in the Stack Overflow Meta.  Moving it here:

The new upper-right icon for "communities" is nearly identical to the Firefox "Open menu" icon, which is also in the upper right.  It is very easy to confuse one for the other.

[image]

Comment: As a note, "complaints" don't generally do well on Meta. We recommend that you phrase your feature request in a more positive way and actually suggest an alternate rather than simply complaining about how things are. If people disagree, you'll still get downvotes but at least they're downvoting the feature rather than the complaint. :D

Answer (score 5):

It's just an [Hamburger button](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburger_button):

> The hamburger (also known as options, hotdog or pancake) button or menu is a button placed typically in a top corner of a graphical user interface. It takes the form of an icon that consists of three parallel horizontal lines (displayed as ☰), suggestive of a list, and is named for its resemblance to the layers in a hamburger, a pile of pancakes, or a hotdog in a long bun.

The reason SE chose it is to save space in the top bar:

> Compared to other computer menus, a hamburger button increases interaction cost **and pay out in less space usage of the screen**

Worth to mention, it's also "nearly identical" to most mobile menu icons:

> [image]

Comment: All this discussion about hamburgers is making me hungry :)